# Jsoup cannot select p element as a parent element

Tags: java, html, dom, jsoup

Using Jsoup I am trying to find wrong html constructions like:

```
<body><p><h1>some text</h1></p></body>
```

I first select the heading tag and then use `headingElement.parent()` to get the parent of this `h1` tag. but instead of `p` as its parent I get `body`.
Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

JSoup, when it parses the HTML, has like any good HTML parser, already applied the rule that says that an `<h1>` tag automatically closes any open `<p>` element, so the `<p>` and the `<h1>` are already sibling children of the `<body>` element in the DOM.

Comment: Can you provide a resource for that please?

Comment: well do you have any suggestions how to solve my problem? i mean finding the correct and wrong combination of tags?

Comment: @Hossein you can't if the standards are against you, but you can get the `p` element as a sibling not as a parent.